Unity долго грузиться на Ubuntu
Поставил Ubuntu версии 24.01.
После редактирования скрипта редактор зависает на несколько минут, тоже самое происхидодит когда делаю билд.
До этого стоял линукс минт 22 все работало нормально и ничего подобного не было
Может есть какой-то способ исправить это?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
